# How can I catch spark.read FileNotFoundException on Spark read?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
def extractor: DataFrame = {
 Try{
  spark.read.schema(myschema).parquet(mypath);
 } match {
   case Success(df) => {
    log("EXTRACTION SUCCESSFUL")  
    df
 }
   case Failure(exception) => {
     log("EXTRACTION UNSUCCESSFUL")
     Seq.empty[myschema].toDF()
   }
  }
}
```

I call this extractor function in my Spark job A. The issue is that `mypath` keeps getting refreshed every half an hour by some other job B. So, when job A reads `mypath` - it catalogues the file names. By the time actual action is performed - the files are changed and the catalogue gets stale and Job A throws an exception - `FileNotFound`.
I want to be able to catch this exception and move on.
But this is what is currently happening -
The above function logs "EXTRACTION SUCCESSFUL"
But Job A throws Job aborted exception which I can see in Yarn.

How can I catch this exception and return an empty data set from the function extractor?

Comment: use cache() and any action like count(), show() etc. to save the dataframe in the memory.

Comment: 1. `Try` is useless when applied like that, rather use `try`; 2. Many questions/answers explain why `return` should not be used in Scala

Comment: You should use `case` instead of `catch` when using `Try` (with a capital `T`)

Comment: @werner I have used case..that was a typo..corrected now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark, and hence your function, is not reading the data in the file, it is just analysing it. The data is read when the action is invoked. As such, you need to catch the exception at the action that you mention.